# Set an excat GoP-length open and no-open in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, h.265, yuv

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 1280x720 -r 50 -pix_fmt uyvy422 
-i Test.yuv -c:v libx265 -x265-params keyint:150:open-gop -b:v 10M Test_open_150_10M.hevc
```

As you can see, I'm trying to convert an yuv-files to a hevc-file with open-GoP and GoP-length 150 and a bitrate 10M. Everything works fine except the open-GoP and the GoP-length. Whatever GoP-length or open/no-open-GoP I try it leads every time to a GoP-length of exact 250 and one Leading Picture (RASL-N). What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `keyint:150` --> `keyint=150`

Comment: Thank you Gyan! I'm sorry, it was just a typing error in the post. The issue still occurs. But when I'm converting it without `:open-gop` at least the gop-length is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the solution:** *`:open-gop=0` for closed GoP, open GoP is automatically enabled so just leave `:open-gop=0` out.*